# order of a subrgoup of rank $r\geq 2$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{F}_p^*$ with orders $o_p(a)=|\langle a  \rangle|=\alpha$ and $o_p(b)=|\langle b  \rangle|=\beta$. I have few questions:

1) Is it true in this case ($\mathbb{F}_p^*$ cyclic) that $o_p(a,b)=|\langle a,b  \rangle| = \rm{lcm}(\alpha,\beta)$? I tried to prove it (supposing it's true!) using primitive roots, i.e. saying that $a=g^k$ and $b=g^h$ for some fixed primitive root $g$, but I got stuck.

2) Does the the previous relation also holds in generic abelian group $G$?

3) Is there a formula for $o_p(a,b,c)=|\langle a,b,c \bmod p\rangle|$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. This holds in any cyclic group. The subgroup $\langle a,b\rangle$ is cyclic as a subgroup of a cyclic group. Use the uniqueness of a subgroup of a given order to get the claim. Your idea of writing everything in terms of the powers of a primitive root also works. The subgroup generated by $g^h$ and $g^k$ is generated by $g^{\gcd(h,k,p-1)}$.

2) No. If $a,b$ are distinct elements of the Klein 4-group, then $\langle a,b\rangle$ has order four, but the lcm is $=2$.

3) Iterating the result from part 1) you get that the order of this group is the l.c.m. of the orders of the three generators.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jyrki! So I have $o_p(a,b,c)=\rm{lcm}(a,\rm{lcm}(b,c))$?

Comment: That's right, if you mean to calculate the lcm of the orders. By part 1) we have $\langle b,c\rangle=\langle d\rangle$, where $o(d)=\mathrm{lcm}(o(b),o(c))$, and then another application of part 1) gives the claim that
$$|\langle a,b,c\rangle|=\mathrm{lcm}(o(a),o(b),o(c)).$$